# CellForRowAtIndexPath is called for invisible cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` of height 450 and i am loading a `UITableView` custom cell of height 480 from the Nib. As per my understanding `CellForRowAtIndexPath` should be called only for visible cells but its called twice in my case. Am I missing something? Please help.Code here

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...

    cell.delegate = self;

    cell.playVideoButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    cell.commentLabel.text = videoPost.post_description;

    cell.videoUrl = videoPost.video;

    QBImageCache *coverImageCache = [[QBImageCache alloc]initWithUrl:coverImageUrl];

    UIImage *coverCache = [coverImageCache fetchImageFromCache];

    if (coverCache != nil) 
    {
        cell.coverImageView.image = coverCache;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.coverImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contestDetailPlaceholder.jpg"];
        coverImageCache.cacheDelegate = self;
        coverImageCache.cacheDuration = 5;
        [coverImageCache fetchImage];
    }

      QBImageCache *profileImageCache = [[QBImageCache alloc]initWithUrl:profileImageUrl];

      UIImage *profileCache = [profileImageCache fetchImageFromCache];

     if (profileCache != nil) 
    {
        cell.profileImageView.image = profileCache;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.profileImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user_avatar.png"];
        profileImageCache.cacheDelegate = self;
        profileImageCache.cacheDuration = 5;
        [profileImageCache fetchImage];
    }
        cell.avMoviePlayer.muted =NO;
        BOOL  visible = [self isIndexPathVisible:indexPath];

    if (visible ) 
    {
        NSLog(@"index inside play video   %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
        [self playVideoIncell:cell];
    }

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: post some code here.

Comment: maybe you reload the data of the tableview twice?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Keep a breakpoint and see if the `indexPath` is different both the times or it is same. If it is same then tableView is being reloaded from somewhere.

Comment: Can you add your code snippet?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @Gandalf Its different both times.      - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath is called for my second cell

Comment: I have added my code. indexPaths are different in both cases but tableView didEndDisplayingCell is called for second cell